# MT4 cannot open file error 4103 when running an EA in Strategy Tester

Tags: file, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4, mt4

I wrote an EA using an indicator which reads in a configuration file. This **configuration file** is put in the folder **`MQL4\Files`**.

When I run the EA with the live chart, it works well. But when I tried to test this EA using the strategy tester, it returns an **`4103 error: can not open file.`**

Any idea why this happens?

And how to address this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A thing that happens is a feature of the MQL4 ecosystem:

> For security reasons, work with files is strictly controlled in the **`MQL4`** language. Files with which file operations are conducted using `MQL4` means, cannot be outside the file ***sandbox***.
>   The file is opened in the folder of the client terminal in the subfolder **`MQL4\files`** ( or **`Tester\Files`** in case of testing ). If **`FILE_COMMON`** is specified among flags, the file is opened in a shared folder for all MetaTrader 4 client terminals.

### How to address this?

Simply, take care of using just the "**relative**" specification of the file-path ( and keep in mind, which of the three possible root-directory cases is being used in which modus-operandi ).

```
aFH = FileOpen( "aFileInsideDefaultDirectoryRoot.txt", ... );
// 
// USED:
// in Strategy Tester---+
//    plain EA-mode-----|------------+
//    FILE_COMMON-mode--|------------|----------------+
//                      |            |                |
// RESULTS:             v            v                v
// in a file in { tester\files | MQL4\Files | <shared_common_directory> }
```

For the case of reading the file, you might enforce to have a copy of the same configuration file in both of the locations for the non-`FILE_COMMON` use-cases, or keep a single instance in `<shared_common_directory>`

Comment: Did you mean you can use `FileOpen("..\..\MQL4\Files\aFileInsideDefaultDirectoryRoot.txt", ...)`? As that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: As an alternative to copying the files, you can use *hardlinking*, see utility: http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html

Comment: **A wonderfull piece, Daniel, thanks for sharing.** Though restricted to NTFS, having ports coverage over wNT/wXP/w2k/wV/w7/w8/w10... is indeed a remarkable O/S footprint. Cool job from Hermann Schinagl et al!